# Use nameservers of another server

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have already a didcated server that uses custom nameservers of my main domain (`ns1.mysite.com` / `ns2.mydomain.com` )

I bought another server & want to use the same nameserver or similar ( `ns3.mysite.com` / `ns4.mysite.com` )

Is this possible? I'm using `WHM/Cpanel` to manage both servers.

Answer (score 3):

While it's not totally clear what you're asking I'll venture to say that yes, it is possible.

1. If you mean that you purchased another domain and you want to host the DNS zone for this domain on your "custom" name servers (although there's no such thing as custom name servers, or custom domains, or custom email addresses) then yes, this is not only possible but very common.
2. If you mean that you purchased another server and you want the new server to use the "custom" name servers for DNS name resolution, then yes, this is possible as long as the "custom" name servers will perform recursive lookups for the new server.

Comment: Thank you  my answer is 2 ! i need to use the old nameservers in the new server. can you please explain 'this is possible as long as the "custom" name servers will perform recursive lookups for the new server.'

Comment: I mean that if the name servers will perform recursive resolution on behalf of DNS clients for domains that the name servers are not authoratative for then this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! i'm a little bit newbie & i'm really stacked in the middle of this

Comment: Glad to help. Make sure to accept my answer, if you accept it.

Comment: Sure, i'm just waiting if anyone else can give me a detailed solution or explain the idea

Comment: @hutchbat Not before you'll formulate reqs in more clean English and in correct jargoon. I can't understand task even in joeqwerty's "translation"

Comment: Let's say my main server A and all the websites hosted on that server use ns1.mybrand.com / ns2.mybrand.com .. i have a second server B, can i use the same namerservers for the new server. i hope that makes sense